# How do I get my program to stop asking questions after the specified amount of questions is asked?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Luke Mihalovich

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int questions = getNumberOfQuestions();
        int difficulty = getQuestionDifficulty();

        while (questions > 0) {

        int random1 = (int)(9 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int random2 = (int)(9 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int randomSign = (int)(4 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int answerAdd;
        int rightAdd;
        int answerSub;
        int rightSub;
        int answerMul;
        int rightMul;
        int answerDiv;
        int rightDiv;

        if(randomSign == 1) {
            System.out.print("Question #" + questions + " What is " + random1 + " + " + random2 + "? ");
            answerAdd = keyboard.nextInt();
            rightAdd = random1 + random2;
            if (answerAdd == rightAdd) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            } else if (answerAdd != rightAdd) {
                System.out.print("Wrong... The answer is " + rightAdd);
            }
        }

        if(randomSign == 2) {
            System.out.print("Question #" + questions + " What is " + random1 + " - " + random2 + "? ");
            answerSub = keyboard.nextInt();
            rightSub = random1 - random2;
            if  (answerSub == rightSub) {
                System.out.print("Correct!");
            } else if (answerSub != rightSub) {
                System.out.print("Wrong... The answer is " + rightSub);
            }
        }

        if(randomSign == 3) {
            System.out.print("Question #" + questions + " What is " + random1 + " * " + random2 + "? ");
            answerMul = keyboard.nextInt();
            rightMul = random1 * random2;
            if  (answerMul == rightMul) {
                System.out.print("Correct!");
            } else if (answerMul != rightMul) {
                System.out.print("Wrong... The answer is " + rightMul);
            }
        }

        if(randomSign == 4) {
            System.out.print("Question #" + questions + " What is " + random1 + " / " + random2 + "? ");
            answerDiv = keyboard.nextInt();
            rightDiv = random1 / random2;
            if  (answerDiv == rightDiv) {
                System.out.print("Correct!");
            } else if (answerDiv != rightDiv) {
                System.out.print("Wrong... The answer is " + rightDiv);
            }
        }
        questions++;
        }   
    }   
        public static int getNumberOfQuestions() {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int questions = 0;

            System.out.print("How many questions do you want? ");
            questions = keyboard.nextInt();

            while(questions < 1) {
                System.out.println("The number of questions must be 1 or more.");
                System.out.print("How many questions do you want? ");
                questions = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        return questions;
}
        public static int getQuestionDifficulty() {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int difficulty = 0;

            System.out.print("What difficulty level do you want (1=low or 2=high)? ");
            difficulty = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (difficulty > 1 | difficulty > 2) {
                System.out.println("Valid levels are 1 or 2. Please reenter. ");
                System.out.print("What difficulty level do you want (1=low or 2=high)? ");
                difficulty = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        return difficulty;
        }
}
```

My program is supposed to ask the user for the amount of questions they want to be asked and then the program is supposed to ask that many randomly generated math questions. What is it I need to fix in my program to stop asking questions after that many is reached? Also how would I get my questions to start at #1? Thanks

Comment: A `for` loop repeats for a fixed number of iterations (usually).

Comment: question-- in while loop

Comment: Use a integer counter variable in your **while** loop: `int counter = 0; while (true) { counter++; System.out.println("Question to ask..."); ..... }`

Comment: @DevilsHnd - why `while(true)` - how does it `break` ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat - Sorry, that's just a simple condition example rather than writing out `questions > 0`. However...to break out of this sort of condition you can use: `if (counter == questions) { break; }`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yeah, I knew that but I do not think the OP would be able to understand

Comment: @Scary Wombat, Yeah, I knew that you knew...lol. Thanks. I definitely should have mentioned that part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop

replace

```
while (questions > 0) {
```

with

```
for (int loop = 1; loop <= questions; loop++) {
```

then also replace code like

```
System.out.print("Question #" + questions + " What is " + random1 + " + " + random2 + "? ");
```

with

```
System.out.print("Question #" + loop + " What is " + random1 + " + " + random2 + "? ");
```

Also, based upon your code comments

```
 while (difficulty > 1 | difficulty > 2) {
```

is wrong and should be

```
while (difficulty != 1 && difficulty != 2) {
```

**edit**

I notice that you have `questions++;` in your code - remove it

Comment: The for loop is still not stopping the program after it reaches the set amount of questions wanted, but the numbering of the questions was fixed, thanks

Comment: I notice that you have `questions++;` in your code - remove it, other wise `loop` will never catch up

Comment: so Luke - what's happening?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: help vampire I'm afraid, one who is continuing to dump his homework here. 1+ for trying